# Manage flash picture with C# and xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, flash

I have created a picture slide show flash and put into a C# website project.

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<flash_parameters copyright="socusoftFSMTheme">
    <preferences>
        <global>
            <basic_property movieWidth="484" movieHeight="402" html_title="Title" loadStyle="Bar" startAutoPlay="true" continuum="true" socusoftMenu="false" backgroundColor="0x002780" hideAdobeMenu="false" photoDynamicShow="true" enableURL="false" transitionArray=""/>
            <title_property showTitle="true" photoTitleColor="0x000080" backgroundColor="0xffffff" alpha="50" autoHide="true"/>
            <music_property path="" stream="true" loop="true"/>
            <photo_property topPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" leftPadding="0" rightPadding="0"/>
            <properties enable="true" backgroundColor="0xffffff" backgroundAlpha="30" cssText="a:link{text-decoration: underline;} a:hover{color:#ff0000; text-decoration: none;} a:active{color:#0000ff;text-decoration: none;} .blue {color:#0000ff; font-size:15px; font-style:italic; text-decoration: underline;} .body{color:#ff5500;font-size:20px;}" align="top"/>
        </global>
        <thumbnail>
            <basic_property showPreview="true" backgroundColor="0x000000" backgroundAlpha="70" buttonColor="0xffffff" numberColor="0x000000" currentNumberColor="0xffffff"/>
        </thumbnail>
    </preferences>
    <album>
        <slide jpegURL="ethumb/t_0001.jpg" d_URL="slides/p_0001.jpg" transition="0" panzoom="1" URLTarget="0" phototime="2" title="t-shirt" width="484" height="402"/>
        <slide jpegURL="ethumb/t_0002.jpg" d_URL="slides/p_0002.jpg" transition="0" panzoom="1" URLTarget="0" phototime="2"  title="golf" width="484" height="402"/>
        <slide jpegURL="ethumb/t_0003.jpg" d_URL="slides/p_0003.jpg" transition="0" panzoom="1" URLTarget="0" phototime="2"  title="ball" width="484" height="402"/>
        <slide jpegURL="ethumb/t_0004.jpg" d_URL="slides/p_0004.jpg" transition="0" panzoom="1" URLTarget="0" phototime="2"  title="shoe" width="484" height="402"/>
        <slide jpegURL="ethumb/t_0005.jpg" d_URL="slides/p_0005.jpg" transition="0" panzoom="1" URLTarget="0" phototime="2"  title="apu" width="484" height="402"/>
</album>
```

And the code i paste in my asp website

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="704" height="402" id="tech">
          <param name="movie" value="flash home.swf?xml_path=home.xml" />
          <param name="quality" value="high" />
          <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
          <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
          <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash home.swf?xml_path=home.xml" width="704" height="402">
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
            <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
          </object>
        </object>
```

So, i want to allow user to insert a new "<"slide">" into xml file between <"album"> <"/album">.

Any help would be appreciate.

Sorry for my poor English.

Thank you.

Comment: C# project using what? Winforms? Silverlight?

Comment: removed asp-classic tag, added asp.net tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this XML to be saved on your server, or just let the user temporarily add things to the local XML that was loaded into his .swf file?

If you want to save it on the server, you'll need to add some sort of functionality to your website (or Flash file) that will let the user upload an image (or link to an image, doesn't matter). You'll need to add a  element to your XML file and the embedded Flash object will need to reload it after it received a response from the server.

If you want just to let the user fiddle with his local copy of the XML, Flash provides libraries to work with XML Data. Check this [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html).

EDIT: Here is an example of how to add an element to an XML.

```
// Load your XML into an XmlDocument
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("your file.xml");

// Create a new element and add attributes
XmlElement newElem = doc.CreateElement("slide");
newElem.SetAttribute("jpegURL", "ethumb/t_0001.jpg");
newElem.SetAttribute("d_URL", "ethumb/t_0001.jpg");
// etc...

// Add the new slide to your album element
doc.DocumentElement["album"].AppendChild(newElem);

// Save the file to your filesystem
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
XmlTextWriter wrtr = new XmlTextWriter("your file.xml", Encoding.Unicode);
doc.WriteTo(wrtr);
wrtr.Close();
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. I wanted to save to the server, what element do i need to add into my XML file? Can i done it just by asp.net code?

Comment: You wanted to add a <slide> element, no? So add a <slide> element. ;) And yes, you can do it in your ASP.NET code.

Comment: i means can i add a <slide> element by using asp.net code? Can you show me example? Thank you